# Can the output of a logic gate be split to serve as input for other logic gates?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

---

[image]

In the textbook picture, they use 5 NOT gates, repeatedly splitting the R input only to have it go into a different NOT gate. Are you allowed to put the input of R into a single NOT gate, and split the output twice? In this case, allowing you to have a total of 3 NOT gates, and 3 AND gates?

Comment: In theory: yes. In practice: as long as drive strengths, frequencies, capaticance and so on allow it, then yes.

Comment: It depends on the logic tech. Check fan-out of logic devices. Having said that, one logic gate output will drive two logic gate inputs pretty much 100% of the time.

Comment: @Puffafish Ok great thanks!

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @greybeard This is for an introductory Discrete Math class where we aren't allowed to simplify the equation or use NAND gates yet, but that approach is what I was thinking too

Answer (score 2):

Having a logic output driving multiple logic input is normal. In ideal logic diagrams, a single logic output could drive an infinite amount of logic inputs, and on many occasions, a clock output will be used on all logic gates that need to run on that clock.

If a logic output could only drive one logic input, it would need a logic device which can internally split a logic signal into two, which again would be paradoxal - inside the chip you would still need to be able to split a logic signal into two.

In real world logic gates, depending on logic family, an output can drive somewhere around 4 to 20 inputs.

Buffers can be used to take a signal in and drive multiple inputs which allows to split a signal into multiple ones that can again drive multiple inputs. But each logic gate or buffer will also add a delay to the signal.